# Problems plotting multiple data sets on same graph in python

Tags: python, plot

I have a dataset which consists of data gathered from experiments from various participants done over 3 days.

I managed to plot the data for each participant on a seperate plot for each experiment succefully using the following code:

```
by_part = p1.groupby('participant_id')
for name, group in by_part:
    byexp_num = p1.groupby('exp_num')
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(len(byexp_num), 5), nrows=2, ncols=(len(byexp_num)//2)+ (len(byexp_num) % 2 > 0)) #as there are 2 rows, the column is by the length of the experiments divided by 2 plus the modulo of the same operation to account for odd numbers
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9,  top=0.8,  wspace=0.4,  hspace=0.4)
    fig.suptitle('Participant {}'.format(name), fontsize=20)
    subplot_targets = zip(byexp_num.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
    for key, ax in subplot_targets:
        ax.plot(byexp_num.get_group(key).rn_norm, byexp_num.get_group(key).scale_data)
        ax.set_ylabel('Scale Data')
        ax.set_title('Experiment {}'.format(key+1))
```

But when I try to group the data in days and plot multiple experiments on the same graph for each day there is a problem with how the graphs are displayed. The data is grouped succesffuly, but it joins the all the experiments together. i.e the line continues from the last datapoint of the experiment to the next so instead of showing n seperate lines in each plot, it shows 1 continuous one. I am not sure about what im doing wrong.

```
by_part = p1.groupby('participant_id')
p1 = df_all[(df_all['participant_id']== 1)]
by_part = p1.groupby('participant_id')
for name, group in by_part:
    by_day = p1.groupby('day')
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 5), nrows=1, ncols=(len(by_day)))
    fig.suptitle('Participant {}'.format(name), fontsize=20)
    subplot_targets = zip(by_day.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
    for key, ax in subplot_targets:
        ax.plot(by_day.get_group(key).rn, by_day.get_group(key).scale_data)
        ax.set_ylabel('Scale Data')
        ax.set_title('Day {}'.format(key))
        ax.legend(p1['exp_num'])
```

Here is the graph it displays.
[Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4joB.png)

EDIT
Adding dataframe as requested by GalacticPonderer

[DataFrame for Participant 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctIc4.png)

Comment: Please can you give us an example of the dataframe?

Comment: Just added a link in the main body @GalacticPonderer

Comment: So you want graphs stacked on top of one another for each day? Have you tried simplifying the problem into a minimum reproducible example -- i.e. determine how to accomplish this interactively with simple dummy data as proof of concept? I tried this with a simple example and was able to make stacked graphs, investigating why you cannot.

Comment: exactly. 3 graphs showing the scale_data for n experiments grouped by day. I am not sure exactly why I cant do it but i suspect its the way i did my grouping.

Comment: @ShafiqJavaid I suspect you are on the right track. You may need to sort by X (ordering Y along with it) to do what you want to do because the points will be connected by lines in the order they are listed in the X array.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to sort your data, per invocation of `plot`, by X value (`rn`). To do this, we'll convert it into a `numpy` array, find out what indexes will sort the X axis, then apply these indices to both the X and Y axis, creating a new `numpy` array we can plot.

First let's look at a simple example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y=[list(range(0,10)), list(range(0,20,2))]
# Randomly chosen out-of-order values
x=[[7,3,8,5,2,1,9,6,4,0],[8,2,4,0,1,6,3,7,9,5]]
fig,axs=plt.subplots()
for i in range(0,2):
    axs.plot(x[i], y[i])

plt.show()
```

Yields:

[image: Unsorted X-axis]

Now let's sort by X axis:

```py
for i in range(0,2):
    xy=np.array([x[i],y[i]])
    ind=np.argsort(xy,axis=-1)[0]
    axs.plot(np.take_along_axis(xy[0,:], ind, axis=0), np.take_along_axis(xy[1,:], ind, axis=0))
```

The `xy=np.array([x[i],y[i]])` line converts the data to a `numpy` array, because `numpy` has the requisite sorting operations. `ind=np.argsort(xy,axis=-1)` returns a `numpy` array of indices that will sort the X-axis, which we will apply to both the X and Y axes. Since we are only interested in the X-axis sort results, we discard the second row (`[0]`). `take_along_axis` is a companion to `argsort` and allows us to apply the indices to the array.
Result:
[image: Sorted by X values]

Applying to your code:

```py
import numpy as np
# [...]
    for key, ax in subplot_targets:
        xy=np.array([by_day.get_group(key).rn, by_day.get_group(key).scale_data])
        ind=np.argsort(xy,axis=-1)[0]
        ax.plot(np.take_along_axis(xy[0,:], ind, axis=0), np.take_along_axis(xy[1,:], ind, axis=0)))
        ax.set_ylabel('Scale Data')
        ax.set_title('Day {}'.format(key))
        ax.legend(p1['exp_num'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look into this as soon as i can. Apologies for late reply life got in the way.